# Part of HTML instead of full using Soup/Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been struggling with the following problem:

I am trying to retrieve the full HTML of a [certain page](https://fd.nl/laatste-nieuws). I've managed to scrape a few other sites, but this one just won't cooperate.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
##########################################

url = "https://fd.nl/laatste-nieuws"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source

page_soup1 = soup(html, "html5lib")

page_soup1
```

The output is just a subpart of the HTML. When I inspect the page through Chrome there are many more elements.

I've tried just using Soup with multiple parsers (html.parser, html5lib and lxml), as well as using Selenium before Soup, both to no avail.

I'm fairly new to all of this so any tips/guides are welcome!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the site is using "*cookiewall*", Just set "Cookie" in headers to "`cookieconsent=true`" and it should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"Host":"fd.nl",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,br",
"Cookie": "cookieconsent=true",
"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://fd.nl/laatste-nieuws"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

for h1, p in zip(soup.select('h1'), soup.select('h1 ~ p')):
    print(h1.text)
    print(p.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Hogere omzet voor Nederlandse zuivelgroep A-ware
Familiebedrijf A-ware bouwt mozzarellafabriek in Heerenveen 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Via negentig procedures van amorfe betonkolos tot hotel met welnesscentrum
Ook fabrieken hebben een levensduur. Niet zelden staan de gebouwen er nog, maar is de oorspronkelijke functie verdwenen. Soms krijgen ze een nieuwe bestemming. In dit eerste deel over industrieel erfgoed: meelfabriek De Sleutels in Leiden.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Egyptische miljardair en oprichter Fortress Investment Group kopen voetbalclub Aston Villa
Nieuwe eigenaren Nassef Sawiris en Wes Edens hopen met hun investering Aston Villa wel snel weer op het hoogste niveau te krijgen.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Greet Prins struint door Marrakesh
Een ideale agenda zonder beperkingen van tijd, afstand of geld. Deze week in de rubriek Droomweekend:  Greet Prins, voorzitter van de raad van bestuur van Philadelphia Zorg.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trump drukt op de beurs, Wall Street licht lager
Koersen op Wall Street dalen nadat Amerikaanse president heeft gezegd 'klaar te zijn om tot 500' mrd aan importheffingen te gaan.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! In the future should I look out for something along the lines of : "<html class="cookiewall"?

Comment: @BaHa Yes, something along these lines - but beware, each site can implement it differently (eg. different cookie name...)